# Installing xv6 on a macOSX 10.15

Tags: macos, terminal, operating-system, cd, xv6

I've been trying to install xv6 on my macOSX through terminal.
I used the command brew install qemu to install qemu and have hit the codes:

```
sudo port install i386-elf-gcc
```

and after modifying the Makefile from i386-jos-elf to i386-elf- I'm receiving the following message on trying to run xv6 when I hit the code:

```
cd xv6-public 
make
```

the following message:

> Error: Couldn't find an i386-*-elf version of GCC/binutils.
> Is the directory with i386-jos-elf-gcc in your PATH?
> If your i386-*-elf toolchain is installed with a command
> prefix other than 'i386-jos-elf-', set your TOOLPREFIX
> environment variable to that prefix and run 'make' again.
> To turn off this error, run 'gmake TOOLPREFIX= ...'.
>
> gcc -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide   -c -o usys.o usys.S

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the xv6 version you downloaded is out of date. I also encountered this problem today. After updating to the latest version, it can be successfully compiled.
The version downloaded with this command seems to be more advanced.

`git clone git://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv-fall19.git`

You can try this tutorial. I succeeded by his method today.
[This is the tutorial but written in Chinese](https://zhayujie.com/mit6828-env.html#comment-98)

Answer (score 1):

- Installing pre-requisite libraries

  ```sh
  brew install python3 gawk gnu-sed gmp mpfr libmpc isl zlib expat
  ```
- Installing the RISC-V GNU toolchain

  ```sh
  brew tap riscv/riscv
  brew install riscv-tools
  path=(/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin ${path})
  ```
- Installing QEMU

  ```sh
  brew install qemu
  ```
- Installing xv6

  ```sh
  git clone --depth 1 --single-branch \
      https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv.git \
      ./xv6
  ```
- Running xv6:

  ```sh
  cd ./xv6
  make qemu
  ```

Answer (score 0):

xv6 Public is not supported with macOS Apple Silicon Chip, rather use xv6-riscv and I suggest you to use docker. Docker make it very easy to use. Follow the installation guidelines from this repo https://hub.docker.com/r/wtakuo/xv6-env.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv.git
```

Instal Docker to your system and pull the image:

```
$ docker pull wtakuo/xv6-env
```

For running the the xv6-riscv in the docker with wtakuo/xv6-env image with the xv6-risc, run the below command:

```
$ cd `path-to-xv6-riscv`
$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xv6/xv6-riscv wtakuo/xv6-env
```

Simply clean the xv-6 repository with the following command:

```
$ make clean
```

After it builds, make and start the emulator by typing in:

```
$ make qemu
```